# move <svg> to the bottom of <div>

Tags: html, css

Id like to make the wave border stick to the bottom of the picture regardless of the size/resolution of the browser window , however adjusting the size of the parent div wont work and neither will setting the border to `top: 100%;`.

[Goal (regardless of screen size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZrzC.png)

Like this, but regardless of how the screen is adjusted

```css
*{
  
}


body{
  background-color:rgb(74,76,81);
}


#welcometoc3 {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 700px;
  left: 75px;
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  font-family: 'gamepixies', 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 125px;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
   }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'gamepixies';
  src: url('/Users/jager/Desktop/dev/dev/Main Projects/Chatting 3 webstie/Chatting 3 webstie/fonts/Gamepixies-8MO6n.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.center-con {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  top: 170px;
  left: 25%;
}

.round {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

span {
  z-index: 10;
  height: 3px;
  margin:1px;
  width: 30px;
  background: rgb(78, 161, 0);
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

span:first-child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 35%;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 45%;
  bottom: 35%;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 54%;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 45%;
  bottom: 54%;
}

.round:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.round:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.round:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.round:hover span:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

#banner-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  clip: (0px,0px,100px,0px);
}

#banner-border {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chatting 3 Hub</title>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainstyle.css">
</head>
<body style="margin:0;"> 
    <div id="banner-border" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><path d="M-13.54,39.95 C123.02,106.08 269.74,52.78 500.00,49.98 L501.12,152.45 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: rgb(74,76,81);"></path></svg></div>     
    <div class="banner">
        <img loop=infinite id="banner-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/8PYMxhg/landscape1.gif" alt="balls">
    </div>
        <div id="welcometoc3" class="fade">Welcome to Chatting 3</div>
    <div>
        <div class="center-con">
            <div class="round">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body{
  background-color:red;
}


#banner-image {
position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  clip: (0px,0px,100px,0px);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#banner-border {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.banner{
position: relative;
height: 100%;
height: 45vh;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banner">
        <img loop=infinite id="banner-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/8PYMxhg/landscape1.gif" alt="balls">
        
        <div id="banner-border" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><path d="M-13.54,39.95 C123.02,106.08 269.74,52.78 500.00,49.98 L501.12,152.45 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: rgb(74,76,81);"></path></svg></div>
        
    </div>
```

You just need to adjust the size of it. As far as I know, you cannot make something relative to the img because this doesn't contain a closing tag so you can't put something inside the image. You need to put them in the same container and adjust their positions.